# How to change the CSS of a background image in a custom HTML module in Joomla?

Tags: html, css, joomla, module

I have a custom HTML module in my Joomla site that in the backend allows you to add a background image to this module. The default formatting/alignment for this image though is the top and left. I am wanting this background image to be aligned to the bottom and right of this module. How can I do this?

I tried (manually and with Firebug) to find the CSS of the background image with no luck. Can someone help me out here? I can't even find the template.css file for the template (chapelco) I am using.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so how we can help you?!

Comment: share us any code or your url or which module you are using

Comment: Sorry but it is currently on localhost so no URL. The module is Custom HTML and under Advanced options you have the choice to add a background image. Whilst it allows you to add one, no where can I find where to change the alignment of the image. I was hoping someone could tell me how to change the alignment of this background image.

Comment: Google >> Joomla module class suffix

Comment: I've looked at this Lodder and yes this is the best way, but I still have the problem of not being able to find the template.css file which is what needs to be changed if the Module Class Suffix is to work

Comment: `templates/your_template_name/css/template.css` should more or less be the location. Start using your browser console which will help locate things such as this

Comment: Yeh it's not there, all I have is master-gecko.css, master-ie8.css, master-ie9.css, master-ie10.css and master-rtl.css. This master file doesn't have much in it and doing a search for the template.css file doesn't come up with anything

Comment: oh so your template is based on a framework...gantry by any chance? Either way, check the forum/documentation for that framework as all information will be there

Comment: Thanks Lodder, yeh it is based on gantry. Will check it out thanks!